# Set database to single user mode for database involved in database mirroring session or an availability group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-mirroring

I'm trying to set a database to single user mode that is currently in an availability group or in a mirroring session. But i'm getting the following error:

```
The operation cannot be performed on database "DATABASE_NAME" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Comment: Why do you want to change a database that is being mirrored or in an availability group to single user?

Comment: To prevent any external alterations to the database while scripts to upgrade it are being run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the database from the availability group, you can use the following command.

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET HADR OFF;  
GO
```

Once you have removed the database from the AlwaysOn AG, then you can put the database in single-user mode.

Comment: Suppose if i do that...and alter the database...then set HADR back ON, then will the change be reflected in the secondary server database?

Comment: Too risky. No other option? I am manage a bank server. I can not take this RISK.